# Problems with exception in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to construct an INSERT INTO query that needs some exception handling.

Here's the code so far:

```
declare
  nvid number := 4561;
  fromMot number;
  toMot number;
begin
  for idx in 1..10 loop
    for fwd in 0..1 loop

      if fwd=0 then fromMot:=idx; toMot:=8; 
      else fromMot:=8; toMot:=idx; 
      End if;

      insert into MOT_BUFFER_TIME(MBT_ID,MBT_NV_ID,MBT_START_MOT_ID,MBT_END_MOT_ID,MBT_BUFFER_TIME)
      values ((select max(mbt.MBT_ID)+1 from MOT_BUFFER_TIME mbt),nvid,fromMot,toMot,600);
      exception
        when dup_val_on_index then 
          UPDATE MOT_BUFFER_TIME set MBT_BUFFER_TIME=600 where MBT_NV_ID=nvid and MBT_START_MOT_ID=fromMot and MBT_END_MOT_ID=toMot;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The table inserts some buffer times (all 600) for a number of MBT_START_MOT_ID and MBT_END_MOT_ID combinations. These are n-8 and 8-n, which I have chosen to do with the nested FOR loops.

The issue is that the table already has some entries (usually 8-5 and 5-8) which have a different value that will need changing to 600, and while MBT_ID is the primary key, there is a constraint that the combination of MBT_NV_ID, MBT_START_MOT_ID and MBT_END_MOT_ID needs to be unique.

So I thought that I would write an exception, such that if there is a duplicate error, I would update instead.

The problem is that that PL/SQL developer is complaining about the placement of `exception`, telling me that it is expecting something else, and also complaining about unexpected `loop` on the penultimate line.

Clearly I've done something wrong, but I can't see what.
Any hints? Thanks.

EDIT: Added "+1" to the first field in the values section, because without it it was pulling off a primary key value that was already used.

Comment: Look at using the MERGE statement.

Comment: EXCEPTION blocks need to be the last item in a BEGIN/END block.

Comment: Add a `BEGIN` immediately before your `INSERT` and an `END;` immediately after the last line of your exception handler.  And, yes, look at using the `MERGE` statement.  There is no need to write code this way.

Comment: if I use MERGE, does that mean that I will first need to create a temporary table with all of the values that I want to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from actually avoiding the problem (e.g. as [OldProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745544/oldprogrammer) suggested), the `EXCEPTION` statement should be a part of a code block, which you do not have, so you have to add `BEGIN` and `END`. Something like this:

```
declare
  nvid number := 4561;
  fromMot number;
  toMot number;
begin
  for idx in 1..10 loop
    for fwd in 0..1 loop

      if fwd=0 then fromMot:=idx; toMot:=8; 
      else fromMot:=8; toMot:=idx; 
      End if;

      BEGIN
        insert into MOT_BUFFER_TIME(MBT_ID,MBT_NV_ID,MBT_START_MOT_ID,MBT_END_MOT_ID,MBT_BUFFER_TIME)
        values ((select max(mbt.MBT_ID)+1 from MOT_BUFFER_TIME mbt),nvid,fromMot,toMot,600);
      exception
        when dup_val_on_index then 
          UPDATE MOT_BUFFER_TIME set MBT_BUFFER_TIME=600 where MBT_NV_ID=nvid and MBT_START_MOT_ID=fromMot and MBT_END_MOT_ID=toMot;
      END;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

**Edited** to match the question edit (as pointed out in the comment).

Comment: That'll be why it didn't work - thank you. Although I have edited my original question because the first field in the `values` section needed to be `(select max(mbt.MBT_ID)+1 from MOT_BUFFER_TIME mbt)` to get a free primary key!